# How to track the source for an non-notification daily alarm?

Tags: alarm, google-pixel-4

Pixel 4, Android 11.

Every day on 12PM an alarm sets off, but no notification.

Only restart can turn it off. How can I track it cause?

Comment: Have you checked `logcat` for entries at that time?

Comment: Which commands would you suggest? `adb logcat *:W | grep "alarm'` ?

Comment: Just catch everything and then carefully read all lines just before and after the time the alarm starts. If you do this two or three times hopefully one or two apps will always be active at that time.